# Kafka Stream KTable-KTable keyed join producing duplicate events(Detected out-of-order KTable)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I Have two stream coming from two topics `orders` and `fsource`. Mainly orders is static and updates rarely while `fsource` getting updated with rate 1000 per seconds. Here I have used `KTable-KTabke` join because they have same key.

```
PObject:
private String orderId;{1,2,3,4,5,6}
private Double price;
private Long oTNum;//{1,2,3,4,5,6}

FSource:
private String orderId;{1,2,3,4,5,6}
private Double adPrice;
private Long fTNum;//{1,2,3,4,5.........} Sequence number for for each event

EnOrder:
private String orderId;
private Double price;
private Double adPrice;
private Long oTNum;
private Long fTNum;
private Long eTNum;//{1,2,3,4,5.........}

        public class EnStreamApp implements PTMS{
            
            private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EnStreamApp.class);
            
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app1-application");
                props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, URL_KAFKA_BROKERS);
                props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
                props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, new JSONSerdeComp<>().getClass());
                props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "C:\\temp");
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        //       props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
                props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10); //commit as fast as possible
                props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);   
                props.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG), 30000);
                
                 
                 
                 StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
                 KTable<String, POrder> pOrderTable = builder.<String, POrder>table("orders"); // Static KTable
                 KTable<String, FSource> fTable = builder.<String, FSource>table("fsource"); // Events 1000 per seconds 
                 
                 KTable<String, EnOrder> enrichedTable = pOrderTable.join(fTable, new ValueJoiner<POrder, FSource, EnOrder>() {

                        @Override
                        public EnOrder apply(POrder order, FSource fSource) {
                            EnOrder enOrder = EnOrder.builder()
                                            .orderId(order.getOrderId())
                                            .price(order.getPrice())
                                            .oTNum(order.getOTNum())
                                            .adPrice(fSource!=null ? fSource.getAdPrice():null)
                                            .fTNum(fSource!=null ? fSource.getFTNum():0)
                                            .eTNum(AtomicSequenceGenerator.INSTANCE.getNext())  // This should be in-sync with events from fSource fTNum                                    
                                            .build();
                            
                            logger.info(String.format("Enriched:{OrderId=%s, oTNum=%s, fTNum=%s, eTNum=%s}", enOrder.getOrderId(), enOrder.getOTNum(), enOrder.getFTNum(), enOrder.getETNum()));
                            return enOrder;
                        }
                    }); 
                
                 
                 enrichedTable.toStream().to("enriched", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerdeComp<>()));

                 KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
                 streams.start();
                 
                 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> streams.close()));
            }

        }


    2020-06-16 14:00:56,577 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-251f1c80-dfcf-433a-a361-5f0fc3cf887e-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=3, oTNum=3, fTNum=232, eTNum=232}
    2020-06-16 14:00:56,578 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-251f1c80-dfcf-433a-a361-5f0fc3cf887e-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=4, oTNum=4, fTNum=233, eTNum=233}
    2020-06-16 14:00:56,578 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-251f1c80-dfcf-433a-a361-5f0fc3cf887e-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=234, eTNum=234}

    2020-06-16 14:18:54,979 WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Detected out-of-order KTable update for fsource-STATE-STORE-0000000003 at offset 9560, partition 0.
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=9564, eTNum=15742}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Detected out-of-order KTable update for fsource-STATE-STORE-0000000003 at offset 9562, partition 0.
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=6, oTNum=6, fTNum=9565, eTNum=15743}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=1, oTNum=1, fTNum=9566, eTNum=15744}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=2, oTNum=2, fTNum=9567, eTNum=15745}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=3, oTNum=3, fTNum=9568, eTNum=15746}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=4, oTNum=4, fTNum=9569, eTNum=15747}
```

Merging of stream looks fine for sometime but when over the period I see duplicate events being processed by `join` function. Ideally one event of `fsource` should result in one event on 'joined stream` then why join is processing more events than it received.

**This looks correct**

```
    2020-06-16 14:00:56,578 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-251f1c80-dfcf-433a-a361-5f0fc3cf887e-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=234, eTNum=234}
```

**This looks NOT right**

```
    2020-06-16 14:18:54,979 WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Detected out-of-order KTable update for fsource-STATE-STORE-0000000003 at offset 9560, partition 0.
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=9564, eTNum=15742}
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Detected out-of-order KTable update for fsource-STATE-STORE-0000000003 at offset 9562, partition 0.
    2020-06-16 14:26:50,799 INFO  com.amicngh.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-82e14b19-9ae3-4ce7-9c1b-a041ccbe70ed-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=6, oTNum=6, fTNum=9565, eTNum=15743}
```

Any idea why join is not working as expected? are these warnings causing this problem? How can I fix this?

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

Any idea why `join` processing duplicate events (see below where I can see multiple `eTNum` values for same `fTNum`)

```
2020-06-17 17:59:05,033 INFO  com.cs.pt.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-47c109a1-d4ad-4d11-a833-9e24d8b99f6b-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=6989, eTNum=120749}
2020-06-17 17:59:19,194 INFO  com.cs.pt.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-47c109a1-d4ad-4d11-a833-9e24d8b99f6b-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=6989, eTNum=139709}
2020-06-17 17:59:33,438 INFO  com.cs.pt.mr.streams.AaggregatorStream [my-app1-aggregation-application-47c109a1-d4ad-4d11-a833-9e24d8b99f6b-StreamThread-1]: Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=6989, eTNum=158669}
```

Answer (score 4):

The warnings are really only warning and they tell you that your input topic partition contain unordered data, i.e., timestamp of records within the same partition go backwards. -- This can be an issue for the correctness of the join, as it expects ordered input data. -- All data would still be processed, but the result might not be correct with regard to the join's time semantics.

Not sure why the output you posted is not expected:

```
Enriched:{OrderId=5, oTNum=5, fTNum=9564, eTNum=15742}
Enriched:{OrderId=6, oTNum=6, fTNum=9565, eTNum=15743}
```

It seems to be two different keys?

Comment: Here `fTNum` is representing a eventId (sequence no) which should match to `eTNum` as one event on fsource should result in one event on enrichment which means value of `fTNum` and `eTNum` should always match. Don't you think so? I just want to mention here I have single partition, single producer to maintain the ordered stream.

Comment: Also I can see joined stream processing same `fTNum` multiple times. Ideally one event should be processed once.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the scenario yet. It's unclear what the _key_ of the input is from your description. The join happens on the key, and I did assume that the key for both inputs is `orderId`? If that is correct, I don't see why `fTNum` should be equal to `eTNum` (expect if `orderId` has the same 1:1 mapping to `fTNum` and `eTNum` in both streams respectively). -- Also if `fsource` or `order` is updated for the same key (ie, `orderId`) the result would be updated accordingly. I don't think that the logs really help, but the input data snippet might help.

Comment: Yes, both input streams have `key` as `orderId`. `expect if orderId has the same 1:1 mapping to fTNum and eTNum in both streams respectively` -> Don't you think this is the case? I mean its a KTable-KTable join which means event on `fsource` with `xyz` `orderId ` will join with `order's` `xyz` key  and will result in one event on merged stream(`eTNum`)?

Comment: If that is the case, I tend to agree. If each topic, contains exactly one record with orderId = xyz, then there should be only one join result. -- Thus, my conclusion is, that your input topic seems to have multiple records with orderId = xyz. -- the `fNum` in the join result you showed in the same, thus I assume that the order-topic has multiple records with the same orderId in it.

Comment: Note that, even if you read a topic as a KTable, processing happens on all data in the topic and if the topic is not perfectly compacted (what is rarely is, as compaction is async) what you observe would make sense. -- Kafka Streams is not batch processor, but does stream processing and thus considers all data in the input topic (not just the latest snapshot of the table), because there is no "final snapshot" anyway.